# What flag has a red star, in a yellow circle, in a green ring, on a red background?

Tags: turkey, poland, flag

[image: Image 2]
The flag is a red star, in a yellow circle, in a green ring, on a red background.

The photo is from [a protest](http://partiarazem.pl/2017/10/hanba-prezydent-gosci-tureckiego-dyktatora/) under the Polish presidential palace against legitimizing the Turkish president Recip Erdogan, organized by a left wing, out-of-parliament "Razem"("Together") party.
Searching on flags.net didn't bring any results and I suspect it has to be an unofficial flag.

There are two more photos available in the link, but I can't link to them due to low reputation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's the flag of the PKK, the [Kurdistan Workers Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Workers%27_Party):

[image]

They are in conflict with Turkey because of civil rights violations against Kurds, as well as a desire for a Kurdish nation.

Answer (score 15):

This flag is the symbol of the [Kurdistan Workers' Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Workers'_Party), also known as the PKK. Their main goal is to establish an independent Kurdish state in a territory currently claimed by Turkey, Iraq and Syria.

Several states, including Turkey, The European Union and the United States, consider it a terrorist organization.